# How to use Repeat and Calc to generate Grid rows based on view width

Tags: html, css

I need to specify the number of rows in a grid basd on the view width divided by 300px.

I'ev also tried *calc(100% / 300)*

But it doesnt seem like the value from Calc is valid in this context

```css
.lct-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(calc(100% / 300px), auto);
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(200px, 300px);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.lct-item {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="lct-grid">
  <div class="lct-item">
    MyItem
  </div>
  <div class="lct-item">
    MyItem
  </div>
  <div class="lct-item">
    MyItem
  </div>
  <div class="lct-item">
    MyItem
  </div>
  <div class="lct-item">
    MyItem
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretty sure `calc` returns a viewport-unit like `px`, which would make it illegal there. Anyways, why do you need this? That doesn't at all seem like something you should do with grid. More like flexbox or maybe columns. Usually with grid you should know your layout exactly.

Comment: I'm currently using Flex but I can't seem to figure out how to be able to have the items grow and still remain the same size when the last row isn't completely filled with items. I just want to fill as many possible items and all items must be the same size. In a grid I can define column width minmax and have the items stretch the width of the column

Comment: With Grid I can auto generate columns and it automatically fills the items on the next row when exceeding the width. So it does everything I need. But not without being able to define how many rows I need.

Comment: I can always set the value using jQuery, but I would preferer a css only solution

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with a mix of CSS and jQuery by setting the z-index on a hidden input element to a specific value on the media query breakpoints. The jQuery reads this value on screen resize and orientation change, then calculates how many rows I need to fill the grid and sets *grid-template-rows*.

> The goal was to make jQuery react to the same breakpoints as the CSS
>   without defining them in both places.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 handleResize();

 $(window).resize(function () {
  resizeDelay(function () {
   handleResize();
  }, 500, unique);
 });

 //jQuery Mobile
 $(window).on("orientationchange", function (event) {
  handleResize();
 });

 function handleResize() {
  let count = $("#grid").find(".item").length;
  let rows = Math.ceil(count / ($("#grid").width() / 300));

  switch (parseInt($("#media").css("z-index"))) {
   case 0:
   case 2:
    rows = count;
    break;
  }

  $("#grid").css("grid-template-rows", "repeat($row, auto)".replace("$row", rows));
 }

 function resizeDelay() {
  var timers = {};

  return function (callback, ms, uniqueId) {
   if (!uniqueId) {
    uniqueId = unique;
   }

   if (timers[uniqueId]) {
    clearTimeout(timers[uniqueId]);
   }

   timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
  };
 }

 var unique = function () {
  return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000).toString(16);
 }();
});
```

```css
#grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-columns: 100%;
    grid-auto-flow: row;
    grid-row-gap: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.item {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: teal;
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    //styles

    #media {
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 1200px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    //styles

    #media {
        z-index: 2;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) and (orientation: landscape) {
 //styles

    #media {
        z-index: 3;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
    //styles

    #media {
        z-index: 4;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>

<div id="grid">
 <div class="item">
  Item
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  Item
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  Item
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  Item
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  Item
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  Item
 </div>
 <div class="item">
  Item
 </div>

 <input id="media" type="hidden" />
</div>
```